How does the variance of the mean enters the theory of confidence intervals?
This semester I'm taking an elementary Physics laboratory class. We're discussing basic probability and statistics and we're interested to apply them to the study of physical measurements. I'm a bit confused by the notion of confidence interval for an estimator. Here I try to formalize my problem in a mathematically sound way.
Let $ (\mathbb R, \mathcal B, \{P_\theta\}_{\theta\in \Theta}) $ be a statistical model, i.e. let $ (\mathbb R, \mathcal B, P_\theta) $ be a Borel probability space for every parameter $ \theta $ in a parameter set $ \Theta $.
Let
$$
(\mathbb R,\mathcal B, \{P_\theta\}_{\theta\in \Theta})^{\otimes n} = (\mathbb R^n,\mathcal B^{\otimes n}, \{P_\theta^{\otimes n}\}_{\theta\in \Theta})
$$
be the product of $ n $ copies of the space, and denote with $ X_i\colon \mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R $ the $ i $-th canonical projection.
Intuitively, think of $ (\mathbb R,\mathcal B, \{P_\theta\}_{\theta\in \Theta}) $ as the stochastic model that underlies a single measurement the kind we do in Physics. Then the space $ (\mathbb R,\mathcal B, \{P_\theta\}_{\theta\in \Theta})^{\otimes\mathbb n} $ models a number $ n $ of independent consecutive measurements, and $ X_i $ is the outcome of the $ i $-th trial.
Now, suppose I go to the lab and measure the same physical quantity for $ n $ times in identical conditions. I obtain a finite sequence $ x_1,\dots,x_n $ of measurements, and I need to choose what to report back to the scientific community. Of course, I want to get a somewhat "best" possible measurement out of the $ x_i $, and in any case I want also to know how much I could be wrong with the reported result.
Question 1. During the course we have defined unbiased estimators for

The expected value of the underlying random variable $ X\sim P_{\theta_0} $, where $ \theta_0 $ is the parameter that ideally identifies the probability distribution that's governs my experiment;
The standard deviation for such an estimator

They are
$$
M = \frac 1n \sum_{i = 1}^nX_i\text{,}\qquad s_M = \frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{(N - 1)}\sum_{i = 1}^n (X_i - M)^2}}{\sqrt n}
$$
I understand that in the limit of $ n $ larger and larger
$$
P_{\theta_0}\bigl(\lvert M_n - E_{\theta_0}[X]\rvert \leqq \epsilon\bigr)\to 1\text{,}\qquad P_{\theta_0}\bigl(\lvert s_M - \operatorname{Var}_{\theta_0}[M]\rvert \leqq \epsilon\bigr)\to 1
$$
for every $ \epsilon > 0 $, but I was wondering, what do I communicate to the scientific community if I say that I measured
$$
\bar x\pm s_{\bar x}\,\text{?}
$$
It's clear to me that in the limit of large $ n $ the mean $ M $ is basically a Gaussian random variable, and that $ E[X] $ is its mean and $ \operatorname{Var}[X]/n $ it's variance. Still the passage from the abstract to the "we take a sample and infer things" case is a bit blurry to me.
Question 2. I read about the notion of confidence interval for a characteristic. Does what we are doing here basically all boil down to the determination of a confidence interval for the characteristic "standard deviation of the mean"? If so, I'm still puzzled, because I'm not sure I grasped the genuine meaning of confidence intervals.
Here's the definition I am using:

Let $ \tau\colon \Theta\to \mathbb R $ be the characteristic we're interested in. A confidence interval for $ \tau $ with error level $ \alpha $ (?), is a mapping $ C\colon \Omega\to \mathscr P(\mathbb R) $ that assigns to each possible outcome $ \omega\in \Omega $ a set $ C(\omega)\in \mathscr P(\mathbb R) $ (an interval) so that
$$
\inf_{\theta\in \Theta} P_\theta\Bigl(\omega\in \Omega : C(\omega)\ni \tau(\theta)\Bigr) \geqq 1 - \alpha
$$
where of course we assume that the sets $ \{C({-})\ni x\} $ are all measurable for $ x\in \mathbb R $.

What does that mean, in words?
Question 2 bis. If the previous guess is correct, how do I compute a confidence interval for the standard deviation of the mean? And for the mean? And what interval should I report back to other experimenters?

I think what you call $s_{\bar x}$ is what is more usually called the standard error of the mean.  You can report the sample mean and its standard error. You can report a confidence interval for the mean  (some people automatically use the sample mean $\pm1.96$ times the standard error, though this is often not appropriate).  I doubt people are interested in a confidence interval for the standard error; a better approach sometimes is to use a $t$-distribution when describing your confidence interval for the mean (so more than $1.96$)
